# Why docker-compose containers doesn't contain host's nameservers?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

bellow you'll find the resolv.conf file of a CentOS host.

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search company.name
nameserver 192.168.xxx.xxx
nameserver 192.168.xxx.xxx
nameserver 192.168.xxx.xxx
```

When running an Alpine docker container, resolv.conf file contains the same information than its host.

```
docker run --rm node:14-alpine cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search company.name
nameserver 192.168.xxx.xxx
nameserver 192.168.xxx.xxx
nameserver 192.168.xxx.xxx
```

Using this docker-compose.yml file, the content of resolv.conf file is different.

```
cat docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  test1:
    image: node:14-alpine
    command: "sleep 10000"
  test2:
    image: node:14-alpine
    command: "sleep 10000"

docker-compose up -d
docker-compose exec test1 cat /etc/resolv.conf
search company.name
nameserver 127.0.0.11
options ndots:0
```

Why are the host's nameservers not included in resolv.conf file when using docker-compose and how to fix it without adding them manually in the docker-compose file (using dns and network_mode: "bridge") ?

Comment: Docker provides its own DNS system (other container names are resolvable to Docker-internal IP addresses) so a container's DNS resolver needs to point at something Docker-provided.  I'd expect the Docker daemon to continue resolution using the host's standard DNS setup if a name doesn't resolve to another container name on the same Docker network.

Comment: Thank you David. I tried to reach a hostname that the host was able to resolve, unfortunately (at least in this case) this hostname wasn't resolved inside the Docker container. But after I read your answer, I tried with the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) and it worked like a charm. So the remaining issue here is now how to resolve a hostname inside the Docker container (instead of the fully qualified domain name) but that's maybe not linked to docker-compose.